# Use default attribute value unless overriden in node attributes

Tags: chef-infra

What would be most polite way to have a default value for an attribute in `chef` that is used in template?

so in `default/attributes.rb` I have a default value:

```
default['my_attribute'] = 'some_default_value'
```

I'd like to override it on some chosen nodes with node attributes:

```
node['my_attribute'] = 'some_defined_value'
```

And in my templates I'd like to just use:

```
@my_attribute
```

which would take value from default['my_attribute'] or node['my_attribute'] (if defined)

What would be the most polite and `Chef`'ish way to do that?

Answer (score 2):

Ohai!

First, I would recommend you have a look at the [attribute-precedence model](http://docs.opscode.com/essentials_cookbook_attribute_files.html#attribute-precedence) for reference.

You are correct, in your attribute file, define something like this (note, it's common practice to namespace attributes after the cookbook):

```
default['cookbook']['attribute'] = 'original_value'
```

And then in a recipe, you can mutate the `node` object by calling `node.set`:

```
node.set['cookbook']['attribute'] = 'new_value'
```

This will save the current node state **and** persist back to the server (if using a Chef Server).

Then, in your `template` resource, just pass the value in directly:

```
template '/tmp/foo.txt' do
  variables(
    :my_attribute => node['cookbook']['attribute']
  )
end
```